# Accessing OpenType glyph variants in iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, opentype

When building PDF documents with OpenType fonts in iText, I want to access glyph variants from within the font -- specifically tabular figures. Since OpenType glyph variants do not have Unicode indices, I am not sure how to either specify that I want to use a particular set of variants (tabular figures) or call a specific glyph by its glyph ID. Just looking for the relevant iText class name if one exists.

Comment: Perhaps [`Class GlyphSubstitutionTableReader`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/fonts/otf/GlyphSubstitutionTableReader.html#getGlyphSubstitutionMap()) is worth a look. It uses [`OpenTypeFontTableReader`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/fonts/otf/OpenTypeFontTableReader.html) - but, at a glance, it seems you have to know in advance which table you want to read. (It's still a bit unclear what one then can do with the raw 'glyph' you get.)

Comment: Would this be off any help?  The `GlyphList` class has a static method: `String unicodeToName(int)` [ http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.pdf.GlyphList ]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does not seem to be possible neither in the latest tag [5.5.8](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/tree/5.5.8), nor in the [master](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/tree/master) branch of iText.

As explained in [this article](http://ilovetypography.com/OpenType/opentype-features.html) and in the Microsoft's [OpenType font file specification](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/gsub.htm), glyph variants are stored in the `Glyph Substitution Table (GSUB)` of a font file. Accessing the glyph variants requires reading this table from the file, which is actually implemented in the class `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.fonts.otf.GlyphSubstitutionTableReader`, though this class is disabled for now.

The call `readGsubTable()` in the class `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontUnicode` is commented out.

```
void process(byte ttfAfm[], boolean preload) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    super.process(ttfAfm, preload);
    //readGsubTable();
}
```

It turns out that this line is disabled for a reason, as the code actually does not work if you try to activate it.

So, unfortunately, there is no way to use glyph variants, as the substitution information is never loaded from the font file.

**Update**

The original answer was about possibility to use `iText API` for accessing glyph variants out of the box, which is not there yet. However, the low level code is in place and can be used after some hacking to access the glyph substitution mapping table.

When called `read()`, the `GlyphSubstitutionTableReader` reads the `GSUB` table and flattens substitutions of all features into one map `Map<Integer, List<Integer>> rawLigatureSubstitutionMap`. The symbolic names of the features are currently discarded by `OpenTypeFontTableReader`. The `rawLigatureSubstitutionMap` maps a `glyphId` variant to a base `glyphId`, or a ligature `glyphId` to a sequence of `glyphIds` like this:

```
629 -> 66 // a.feature -> a
715 -> 71, 71, 77 // ffl ligature
```

This mapping can be reversed to get all variants for a base `glyphId`. So all extended glyphs with unknown unicode values can be figured out through their connection to a base glyph, or a sequence of glyphs.

Next, to be able to write a glyph to PDF, we need to know a unicode value for that `glyphId`. A relationship `unicode -> glyphId` is mapped by a `cmap31` field in `TrueTypeFont`. Reversing the map gives unicode by glyphId.

**Tweaking**

`rawLigatureSubstitutionMap` cannot be accessed in `GlyphSubstitutionTableReader`, as it's a `private` member and does not have a getter accessor. The simplest hack would be to copy-paste the original class and add a getter for the map:

```
public class HackedGlyphSubstitutionTableReader extends OpenTypeFontTableReader {

    // copy-pasted code ...

    public Map<Integer, List<Integer>> getRawSubstitutionMap() {
        return rawLigatureSubstitutionMap;
    }
}
```

Next problem is that `GlyphSubstitutionTableReader` needs an offset for `GSUB` table, information that is stored in `protected HashMap<String, int[]> tables` of `TrueTypeFont` class. A helper class placed into same package will bridge access to the protected members of `TrueTypeFont`.

```
package com.itextpdf.text.pdf;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.fonts.otf.FontReadingException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class GsubHelper {
    private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> rawSubstitutionMap;

    public GsubHelper(TrueTypeFont font) {
        // get tables offsets from the font instance
        Map<String, int[]> tables = font.tables;
        if (tables.get("GSUB") != null) {
            HackedGlyphSubstitutionTableReader gsubReader;
            try {
                gsubReader = new HackedGlyphSubstitutionTableReader(
                        font.rf, tables.get("GSUB")[0], glyphToCharacterMap, font.glyphWidthsByIndex);
                gsubReader.read();
            } catch (IOException | FontReadingException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage());
            }
            rawSubstitutionMap = gsubReader.getRawSubstitutionMap();
        }
    }

    /** Returns a glyphId substitution map
     */
    public Map<Integer, List<Integer>> getRawSubstitutionMap() {
        return rawSubstitutionMap;
    }
}
```

It would be nicer to extend `TrueTypeFont`, but that would not work with factory methods `createFont()` of `BaseFont`, which relies on hard coded class names when creating a font.

Comment: You speak and cite with authority; yet, I find it hard to believe it is not possible to parse GSUB tables with Java. Do you mean to say that even if you *can* parse a GSUB table, iText does not contain the infrastructure to work with "raw" glyph indices, and so as part of adding GSUB replacements, the current text handling paradigm of iText would need replacing in its entirety?

Comment: Sorry, my answer is really too categorical, even foolish. It does not reflect the full truth. What I meant was that the API for using glyph substitutions is unfinished in the current version of iText. But the infrastructure is mainly in place. It can be used with some copy-pasting and tweaking of iText classes. I'm going to update my answer with more details.

Comment: I think the low level of GSUB is ok. Every section of data seems to be parsed from the file (there are no tests for this functionality though). But the API level is unfinished, the raw data stay encapsulated inside the infrastructure classes, not delivered to API through meaningful use cases. At the same token, the key iText classes in this story are not designed for extension, which makes it difficult to customize the solution.

Comment: I think you are confusing the `master` and the `develop` branches. The tip of the `master` branch is always identical to the latest release tag. The `develop` branch contains the current (pre-release) development. I should know, because I am the person who created the tags. :)

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Yes, you're right, I do :) But it does not matter for the part of code this story concerns. It was not changed since 7-10 month ago, long before the latest release tag.